# Como enviar varios sms por um aplicativo android

Tags: android, sms

No meu aplicativo estou tentando fazer o envio de vários SMSs, mas algumas vezes ele não envia.

```
smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage (telefones.get(i), null,smsManager.divideMessage("Mensagem"), null, null);

try {
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    for (int i = 0; i < telefones.size(); i++) {
        smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(telefones.get(i), null, "foo"), null, null);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Tenho um Arraylist com os telefones , ai eu tento enviar sms para todos do vetor com um for e usando o smsManager, mais as vezes não envia , alguem sabe se e problema desta classe?

Comment: tem duas linhas que pode ser enviado 
 smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(telefones.get(i), null, smsManager.divideMessage("Chegou a hora! " + bebe.nomeBebe + " está chegando. Partiu " + bebe.maternidade + "!\nAss: " + bebe.nomePai + " e " + bebe.nomeMae + "\n(App Chegou a Hora)"), null, null);

Comment: Uma consideração importante: [tente fazer um exemplo mínimo de código que possa ser usado na resolução](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A lógica que verifica se um bebê tem pai não tem nada a ver com o problema do envio de SMS. Evite colocar código além do problema pois isso é motivo suficiente para fechar a pergunta, ok? Neste caso reduzi o código na pergunta para ficar legível e conter somente as partes relevantes.

Comment: ta bom , não sabia isso ue só coloquei a parte do codigo que envia

Comment: @IlgnerdeOliveira você pode encontrar mais informações fazendo um [tour] :)

Comment: aff pq suspendeu minha pergunta :/ assim fica dificil ser ajudado aqui

Comment: Talvez falte mais informações para o pessoal conseguir responder. Mas estou reabrindo a pergunta.

Comment: Chega a da erro? Ou apenas não chega a mensagem no celular... dentro do seu for utilize tbm o smsManager.divideMessage(), não sei como vc ta passando os seus dados mas alguns caracteres as vezes fica codificado fazendo que isso aconteça, já tivesse esse problema especialmente com '#'.

Comment: nem chega a da erro flavio, simplesmente não chega , ja estou usando o smsManager.divideMessage() , e que eu simplifiquei um pouco o código pq pediram